# Brake Adjustor Help

Tags: brakes

Could somebody help me identify this? I need to buy one for my bike but I can't find much online. I've asked in numerous shops but none of them have this type of adjuster with the flat side. I think it may be Campagnolo.[image]

Comment: At least older Campagnolo has that flat side. Can you post a photo of the brake this is from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a barrel adjuster. Why do you need a Campagnolo one? If it fits, it works.

If you really want a Campy, I'd try eBay now that you know what it's called. The one in the top left has the flat side you want. Note that a non-Campy adjuster would be 2-5 eurodollars each....

[image: campy barrel adjuster]

I'd also check with older, grimier bike shops that look like they've been around forever, they usually have a parts bin with finds such as this.  They would usually give it to you for free if you're a regular or for beer money if you're not.